# How can I parse logs with SparkR or SparklyR?

Tags: regex, logging, pyspark, sparkr, sparklyr

I am trying to parse NASA-HTTP logs with SparkR/SparklyR whichever I can. I am unable to get it to work.

NASA-HTTP logs look like this

```
ix-stp-fl2-19.ix.netcom.com - - [03/Aug/1995:23:03:09 -0400] "GET /images/faq.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 263
slip183-1.kw.jp.ibm.net - - [04/Aug/1995:18:42:17 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-70/images/DSC-95EC-0001.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 107133
piweba4y.prodigy.com - - [05/Aug/1995:19:17:41 -0400] "GET /icons/menu.xbm HTTP/1.0" 200 527
```

I have been able to do this with Pyspark using regexp_extract as follows

```
split_df = base_df.select(regexp_extract('value', r'^([^\s]+\s)', 1).alias('host'),
                          regexp_extract('value', r'^.*\[(\d\d\/\w{3}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} -\d{4})]', 1).alias('timestamp'),
     ....
```

I am trying to do this with SparkR/Sparkly R and have made no progress

```
# Initiate a SparkR session
sparkR.session()
sc <- sparkR.init()
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
df <- read.text(sqlContext, "/FileStore/tables/NASA_access_log*.gz")
```

Tried a couple of things but was of no use

```
sparkR.session()
sc <- sparkR.init()
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
df <- read.text(sqlContext, "/FileStore/tables/NASA_access_log*.gz")
dim(df)
df %>% select(df,regexp_extract('\\\\S'),1)
```

Please let me know how to progress in using regular expressions on the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking around the internet and trying out a multitude of things for a day and a half,  I was able to parse the logs in both SparkR and sparklyR

### SparkR

```
# Initiate a SparkR session
sparkR.session()
sc <- sparkR.session()
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
df <- read.text(sqlContext,"/FileStore/tables/NASA_access_log*.gz")


a=df %>% 
  withColumn('regex1', regexp_extract(df$value, '^(\\S+)', 1)) %>%
  withColumn('regex2', regexp_extract(df$value, "((\\S+ -\\d{4}))", 2)) %>%
  withColumn('regex3', regexp_extract(df$value, '(\\"\\w+\\s+([^\\s]+)\\s+HTTP.*")', 2))  %>%
  withColumn('regex4', regexp_extract(df$value, '(^.*"\\s+([^\\s]+))', 2)) %>%
  withColumn('regex5', regexp_extract(df$value, '(^.*\\s+(\\d+)$)', 2))
head(SparkR::collect(a))


               regex1                      regex2
1         199.72.81.55 [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400
2 unicomp6.unicomp.net [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400
3       199.120.110.21 [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400
4   burger.letters.com [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400
5       199.120.110.21 [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400
6   burger.letters.com [01/Jul/1995:00:00:12 -0400
                                           regex3 regex4 regex5
1                                /history/apollo/    200   6245
2                             /shuttle/countdown/    200   3985
3    /shuttle/missions/sts-73/mission-sts-73.html    200   4085
4                 /shuttle/countdown/liftoff.html    304      0
5 /shuttle/missions/sts-73/sts-73-patch-small.gif    200   4179
6                      /images/NASA-logosmall.gif    304      0
```

### SparklyR

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
#sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.1.0")
sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks")
sdf <-spark_read_text(sc, name="df", path = "/FileStore/tables/NASA_access_log*.gz")
sdf <- sdf %>% mutate(regex = regexp_extract(line, '^(\\\\S+)',1)) %>% 
               mutate(regex1 = regexp_extract(line, '((\\\\S+ -\\\\d{4}))',2)) %>%
               mutate(regex2 = regexp_extract(line, '(\\\\"\\\\w+\\\\s+([^\\\\s]+)\\\\s+HTTP.*")',2)) %>%
               mutate(regex3 = regexp_extract(line, '(^.*"\\\\s+([^\\\\s]+))',2)) %>%
               mutate(regex4 = regexp_extract(line, '(^.*\\\\s+(\\\\d+)$)',2))
sdf


   line                     regex     regex1      regex2           regex3 regex4

 1 "199.72.81.55 - - [01/J… 199.72.8… [01/Jul/19… /history/apollo/ 200    6245  
 2 "unicomp6.unicomp.net -… unicomp6… [01/Jul/19… /shuttle/countd… 200    3985  
 3 "199.120.110.21 - - [01… 199.120.… [01/Jul/19… /shuttle/missio… 200    4085  
 4 "burger.letters.com - -… burger.l… [01/Jul/19… /shuttle/countd… 304    0     
 5 "199.120.110.21 - - [01… 199.120.… [01/Jul/19… /shuttle/missio… 200    4179  
 6 "burger.letters.com - -… burger.l… [01/Jul/19… /images/NASA-lo… 304    0     
 7 "burger.letters.com - -… burger.l… [01/Jul/19… /shuttle/countd… 200    0
```